# Convert DATE to TIMESTAMP on BigQuery/StandardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am querying a table on BigQuery that has a field in the 'DATE' format. I want to read this in the 'TIMESTAMP' format. I tried converting the DATE to an integer and then converting into a TIMESTAMP but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS dt
)
SELECT dt, CAST(dt AS TIMESTAMP) AS ts,
  TIMESTAMP(dt) AS ts2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row dt          ts                           ts2
1   2018-06-13  2018-06-13 00:00:00.000 UTC  2018-06-13 00:00:00.000 UTC
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I did convert by mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nash just leaving [the appropriate documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) here, in case it is useful for you.

Comment: @dsesto Thanks :)

Comment: @Nash - you can also use TIMESTAMP() that can convert  a DATE data type to a TIMESTAMP data type